# Polynomial time algorithm to compute minimum distance of a linear code

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, coding-theory

For general (even binary I believe) linear codes, computing the minimum distance $\min_{d \in C} \Delta(d, 0)$ is NP-complete. However, there is a special case where a polytime algorithm is possible:

Consider a connected graph $G = (V, E)$ and define a code $C \subseteq \mathbb{F}_2^{|E|}$ as follows:

For every $U \subseteq V$, let $n(U) \subseteq E$ be the boundary of $U$- it contains all the edges such that one end is in $U$ and the other is outside $U$.

Put some arbitrary numbering on $E$.

Then define the code for $U$, $c(U) \in \mathbb{F}_2^{|E|}$ where $c(U)_i = 1\iff $ edge $i \in n(U)$.

This is a linear code since $c(U_1) + c(U_2) = c(U_1 \Delta U_2)$ (this is easily seen).

Given this coding- I am looking for a polytime algorithm (in $|V|$) that computes the minimum distance of the code, i.e, $\min_{d \in C} \Delta(d, 0)$ where $\Delta$ is the Hamming distance.

There was another similar question about the setup that asked to compute the dimension of this code but I was unable to do that either.

This seems too dependent on the specific structure of $G$, but all we know is its connected so I'm a bit lost for this.

Comment: I saw your earlier question. FWIW I think the dimension of the linear space is $n-1$ w $n$ the number of vertices. Note that the $c(\{v\})$s; $v$ a vertex; added all together the zero vector so it is no more than $n-1$. That $G$ is connected means [I think!] that all $n$ of these $c(\{v\})$ are needed in a linear combination to add to the zero vector